# nDepend - The assembly {assembly name} is not in sync with corresponding coverage data

Tags: code-coverage, static-analysis, ndepend

When importing a VSTS coverage data file to a NDepend project I'm getting an error message *"The assembly {assembly name} is not in sync with corresponding coverage data."*. This project analyzes 3 assemblies and the coverage data for the 3 assemblies is grouped in the same coverage data file, but the error message only appears for one of these assemblies. For the other two assemblies everything works fine.

I tried searching the web, but couldn't find any information about this error. Have anyone seen this error before?

Comment: Has the assembly been modified after the coverage was run? Is there anything unusual about that assembly compared to the others that means that what was instrumented my be not what is now being seen i.e. mocking, code contracts or soemthing that may modifiy the assembly?

Comment: this might be a side-effect of an identified bug on VS code coverage that will hopefully be fixed within the next weeks. Drop us an email at *support at NO SPAM ndepend dot com* if you wish to test the upcoming fix in beta.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Patrick. I sent you an email regarding testing the fix in beta.

Comment: No, the assembly is not modified after instrumentation. The build and instrumentation process is the same as the other assemblies. Seems like the issue is the bug that Patrick talked about.